# How to create an edit form for admin input

Tags: forms

I would like to create from a module an add/edit form.

For now I made an add form that looks like this:

```
$form["locationTitle"] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas nosaukums"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. Rīga"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationsLat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas platums"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. 56.966058"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationLng'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas garums"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. 24.162004"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas pirmdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. P 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas otrdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. O 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas trešdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. T 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay4'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas ceturdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. C 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay5'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas piektdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. Pk 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay6'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas sestdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. S 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDay7'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas svētdienas darba laiks"),
    '#description' => t("Piem. Sv 8.00 - 20.00"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationTel'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas telefona nr."),
    '#description' => t("Piem. Telefons +371 67225566 Mob +371 28301555"),
    '#required' => true
);

$form['locationDescription'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Vietas apraksts"),
);

$form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Pievienot')
);
```

I would like an edit version where admin selects one of locations entered and then can edit them. I thought i could add a combobox and let the person pick if wants to edit something or create a new one. The though was to have it all in the same form.. And then it would be dynamic in the choice.

But I dont really have a much of a clue what could i substitute the combobox with.. And If it is even possible to make it that dynamic.

Thanks for help :)